# Saving object attributes using a function

Tags: r, object, attributes, save

I'm trying to modify the save() function so that the script from which the object originated is stored as an attribute of the object.

```
s = function(object, filepath, original.script.name){
  #modified save() function
  #stores the name of the script from which the object originates as an attribute, then saves as normal
  attr(object, "original.script") = original.script.name
  save(object, file = filepath)
}
```

Sample:

```
testob = 1:10
testob
#  [1]  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10
s(testob, filepath = "rotation1scripts_v4/saved.objects/testob", "this.is.the.name")
load(file = "rotation1scripts_v4/saved.objects/testob")
testob
#  [1]  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10
attributes(testob)
# NULL
```

Investigating further, it seems that the object is not being loaded into the environment:

```
testob2 = 1:5
testob2
# [1] 1 2 3 4 5
s(testob2, "rotation1scripts_v4/saved.objects/testob2", "this.is.the.name")
rm(testob2)
load(file = "rotation1scripts_v4/saved.objects/testob2")
testob2
# Error: object 'testob2' not found
```

Why isn't it working?

Comment: When asking for help, you should include a simple [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) with sample input and desired output that can be used to test and verify possible solutions. How exactly are you calling this function? How are you verifying that the attributes are not preserved?

Comment: Hi MrFlick, see updated post for example. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to be careful with `save()`. It saves variables with the same name that's passed to `save()`. So When you call `save(object, ...)`, it's saving the variable as "object" and not "testob" which you seem to be expecting. You can do some non-standard environment shuffling to make this work though. Try

```
s <- function(object, filepath, original.script.name){
  objectname <- deparse(substitute(object))
  attr(object, "original.script") = original.script.name
  save_envir <- new.env()
  save_envir[[objectname]] <- object
  save(list=objectname, file = filepath, envir=save_envir)
}
```

We use `deparse(substitute())` to the get name of the variable passed to the function. Then we create a new environment where we can create the object with the same name. This way we can use that name when actually saving the object.

This appears to work if we test with

```
testob <- 1:10
s(testob, filepath = "test.rdata", "this.is.the.name")
rm(testob)
load(file = "test.rdata")
testob
#  [1]  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10
# attr(,"original.script")
# [1] "this.is.the.name"
```